# Runge-Kutta method for $y'(x)= \sin(y)$ with $y(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems, runge-kutta-methods

I have the following IVP, which I need to solve using Runge-Kutta methods.

$$y'(x)= \sin(y), \qquad y(0)=1$$

The range is $[0,1]$. My problem is that I need to choose the step size $h$ such that the error will be in order of $0.0001$. How do I choose the right $h$ for the required error?

Comment: Standard Runge-Kutta 4th order is $O(h^4)$ accurate. Use trial and error to see if your results agree.

Comment: thank you @Arkamis. consider i use trial and error, my question is how to calculate the error of my results?

Comment: At any given point $x = x_n$, the error is simply $\left|\textrm{actual_solution}(x_n) - \textrm{approximate_solution}(x_n)\right|$

Comment: i know but i can't find a way to calcualte the actual solution. the matlab fuction requires number of step, and i need to discover number of step. i think its supposed to be big number of steps so it can't be done manual.

Comment: The actual solution is absolutely trivial. Look more carefully.

Comment: @Amzoti hey, thanks! i tried but the error is not 0.0001. there is a way to find the h without trial and error ? i tried a lot of options and i do not get the required error.

Comment: @Amzoti how i can see that? i have found that the differential equation solution is 2*cot^(-1)(e^(-x)cot(0.5)).  i choose an x for this equation and try it also on my function of RK, with h= 0.0001. calculating the error by |actual_solution-approximate_solution| and got 0.000099 error, that is very close to what i need. you think i did it correctly?

Comment: The question is also, which error you are referring to. L2 Norm, Maximum Norm? Your analytic solution is correct.